# Mystery: Drupal loading old version of file

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I am working on changing a Drupal 7 site and have run into strange behavior where an old version of a file I've changed keeps re-appearing.  I've flushed caches via the admin interface as well as truncating the cache_ tables.

On my staging server (which I have access to), things work fine.  On our production server (which I do not have SSH access to and cannot easily get access to), they do not and I have limited ability to debug, so I have to guess.  I suspect there is some Drupal or Apache setting that is causing these old files to be shown because the filesystem has identical contents.  The behavior is almost as if Drupal will look for any file named the same (even if it is in the wrong directory) and show that.

In my case, I have all my files under /var/www/html (standard LAMP setup).  At one point, I tar cfz the entire thing and kept that at /var/www/html/archive.tgz (not removing it by mistake).  So now I'm wondering if somehow Drupal is reading the contents of that archive and using the old file.  Sounds crazy, but has anyone run into something like that?

The other possibility is that my cache cleaning is still limited in some way.  Outside of truncating cache_ tables in the database, is there any way to forcibly remove all cached entries?  Any insight into this mystery would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this from a URL request in a browser?

Comment: yes, i see evidence of the problem because a path does not render as expected (e.g., wrong stylesheet is being used)

Comment: for example, i browse to some node (e..g, /node/1) and the basic content looks fine, but one of the stylesheets (which is under /sites/default/themes/mytheme/templates/style.css) is not the latest version

Comment: Would doing something like `/node/1?itok=randomstring` make things any better? If so then it's definitely a caching issue

Comment: good point, i will try that...

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, your production server runs some additional caching proxy like [Varnish](https://varnish-cache.org/index.html). You need to clear cache there as well.